# Only allow donations from PayPal balance?

Tags: php, paypal

In PHP how would I allow only donations from PayPal balance and not from a credit card? Is there any example code you can provide or code out there which could help?

Comment: I think you need to give us more of a setup.  Also, please go back and accept some answers from your previous questions.

Comment: My setup is a PHP donation script - which I found on the net. However I've found sometimes donations get disputed (especially when the donator is using a CC) - which annoys me as if their donating why do that?. I can't accept answers on some of my previous questions (which I think theirs 2 unanswered) as theirs nothing which I consider an answer (that helped me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant.  That'd be controlled on the paypal side, and Im pretty sure there is not an option for that.